# Laravel 5 route to controller outside the namespace or route to another controller

Tags: laravel-5

I want to route to a adminController which is located under Administration Module : `App\Modules\Administration\Http\Controller` to perform addUser action.

To call the AdminController, i am using the route.php located under `App\Modules\User`. Below is my `route.php` in user module.

```
Route::group(array('namespace'=>'App\Modules\Administration\Http\Controllers'), function(){

        Route::post('/addUser', [
            'uses' => 'adminController@addUser',
            'as' => 'addUser'
        ]);

    });
```

But i am getting error saying route does not exist. can you help me out?.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify that you want to use the routes.php located at `App\Modules\User` editing your `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` like so:

```
/**
 * Define the routes for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
 * @return void
 */
public function map(Router $router)
{
    $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router) {
        require app_path('App\Modules\User');
    });
}
```

Otherwise, you can use the default routes.php located at `app/Http/Requests`

Comment: show them, and if you are still using routes in your default routes.php require both

Comment: This is the error i am getting:ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
Class App\Modules\Userlogin\Http\Controllers\App\Modules\Administration\Http\Controllers\adminController does not exist....i required both the routes....trying to route from User Module to Admin controller under Admin Module

Comment: mmm ok, looks a problem about namespaces, quit it. $router->group([], function ($router) {
        require app_path('App\Modules\User');
    });

Comment: my user module has its own routeserviceprovider which is prefixing this line: App\Modules\Userlogin\Http\Controllers\

Comment: try without specifying the namespace

Comment: keeping the namespace empty in routeserviceprovider under User Module gives me this error: ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:

Class \App\Modules\Administration\Http\Controllers\adminController does not exist

Comment: the route to controller path is correct but it says that controller doesn't exist

Comment: Which namespace are you using in your controller class? It should be set up to `namespace App\Modules\Administration\Http\Controllers;`